# How to Customize the ApiClient Class Name in openapi-generator-maven-plugin for Maven?

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin in a Maven project to generate a client based on an OpenAPI specification. The generated client includes a class named ApiClient by default, located in the package com.somthing.java.api_client.generated. I need to rename this ApiClient class to HelloworldApiClient to adhere to our project naming conventions.
Here is the relevant portion of my pom.xml configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
  <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <inputSpec>${project.build.directory}/${open-specification.path}</inputSpec>
        <generatorName>java</generatorName>
        <library>feign</library>
        <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
        <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
        <apiPackage>com.somthing.spring.api_client.generated.api</apiPackage>
        <modelPackage>com.somthing.somthing.api_client.generated.model</modelPackage>
        <configOptions>
          <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
        </configOptions>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there a way to directly configure the plugin or provide an additional configuration to rename the `ApiClient` class to `HelloworldApiClient`? Alternatively, are there any best practices or workarounds involving scripts or custom generator templates that can achieve this result?

Any guidance or insights on customizing the generated client names, especially for the `ApiClient` class, would be greatly appreciated.